# SQL Rounding a non decimal number

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way in sql to round the non decimal numbers?

> Example : 
>   SQL fetch data : 4566
>   Display data : 4600

Comment: I remember covering this in primary school

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

```
SELECT ROUND(4566, -2)
```

There is a [ROUND](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_round) method for `MySQL` which accepts 2 parameters:

- Value: value itself like in my example above, or `COLUMN` name
- Decimals: Normally behaves in the right hand side of decimal point. You'll just have to use `NEGATIVE` value to round the value in the left hand side.

Comment: It gave me an output of 4600. That's good.
Now I have this 4523. Is there a way to make it display 4600. Instead of 4500?

Comment: 4523 normally rounds to 4500, which is round-half-up rule. If you need something else, please state the specific condition that you need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the value by 100, then round, and then multiply with 100 again.

```
SELECT ROUND(4566 / 100.0) * 100;
```

Comment: Works good! Thanks.!